# Getting an error on accessing an array from ini file to zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, ini, zend-config

In my config.ini file given

```
customer.login.test = "test case" 
customer.login.support[] = "abel"
customer.login.support[] = "justin"
customer.login.support[] = "leon"
```

I tried to access it in zend action helper function as

```
$config = \Zend_Registry::get("config");
echo $config->customer->login->test; // Outputs as "test case"

print_r($config->customer->login->support); // No Result

print_r($config->customer->login->support->toArray()); // Gives Error
```

ERROR: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

How to correct this problem?

**EDIT:**

```
support[] = "abel"
support[] = "justin"
support[] = "leon"
```

In zend action helper function

```
print_r($config->support->toArray());
```

Above `print_r` statement gives me a correct array. How this happens?

Comment: check the config file, code if perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried your code. It works fine.
It looks like you don't set `customer.login.support[]`.

This can happen if you load another section of config file (e.g. `testing` instead of `development`) which also have `customer.login.test` but doesn't have `customer.login.support[]`

Comment: No, I have `customer.login.support[]` development section itself. If  I try with `support[]`, it is working nice.